# What's the name of the iOS / OS X calculator app that has 'variables' functionality?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I'm looking for an app on the App Store but I forgot its name.

It is a calculator app that looks like it has been written on a noteblock.

You can store the solutions of calculations as quasi-variables and then reuse them later on.

I know it's available for the Mac and all iOS devices.

Does anyone know what app this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like the app [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/) which is available on Mac OS X and iOS.  It allows you to use a mixture of natural language and spreadsheet/calculator functions to perform easily readable equations.

[image: Soulver]

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be [Numi](http://getnumi.info/), which describes itself as follows:

> Numi is a little calculator, that lives in your menu bar. It magically
>   combines calculations with text, and allows you to share computations
>   with other Numi users.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: The link could disappear, and even it it was still there say next year, you are requiring the user to leave the site to view the answer, which is a poor user experience.  Links are great, but you should summarise them also.  I have amended your post for an example of how to do it.  You can see the full changes in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as well http://www.swiftcalc-mac.com It has variables and can calculate many expressions at once